# Moving a JLabel for a game

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I am coding a Backgammon game that plays by itself. While the backend code is mostly done, me and my colleague have pretty much no experience in GUI coding. We used the Designer given by a plugin for Eclipse and most of the code was generated.

So here's the thing. Right now there is a `JFram`e which has a `JPanel` in which are 2 `JLabels`, one for the background and one for 1 playing piece (when I figure this out, the rest of them will be added). These are all in an `initialize()` method which is run through `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable())`. After the board and the piece are drawn, the `startGame()` method is called, which finally comes to a method called `movePiece()`, with the sole purpose of moving that `JLabel` piece I talked about before.

I have tried mostly everything I can think of, I have scoured the forums and only found people talking about layouts (which I may or may not be using, as I said, generated code) and the darn `JLabel` won't move when I call  `setLocation()` inside the `movePiece()` method. It always throws a `NullPointerException` at that line which is bizarre because the image is already drawn. I will include part of the code below.
 I know this will probably look like some of the worse codes ever, but please bear with my lack of skill and help me make this better. Any insights?

```
public class Main{

public JLabel image1;

private JFrame frame;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {

                Main window = new Main();

                window.frame.setVisible(true);
                new Main(1);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
public Main() {
    initialize();

}

public Main(int i){
    startGame();
}

public void startGame() {
    //game code
    movePiece(Move.getPos(), Move.getDest());
    //rest of code
}

public void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1023, 617);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 700));

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 700));
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1, BorderLayout.EAST);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Start Game");

    /* ACTION LISTENER FOR THE BUTTON */

    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });

    btnNewButton.setFocusable(false);
    btnNewButton.setForeground(SystemColor.windowBorder);
    btnNewButton.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
    btnNewButton.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);
    btnNewButton.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    btnNewButton.setRolloverEnabled(false);
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    btnNewButton.setDebugGraphicsOptions(DebugGraphics.NONE_OPTION);

    /* ADDING THE BTN TO PANEL 1 TO THE RIGHT */
    panel_1.add(btnNewButton);
    JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();
    parentPanel.setFocusable(false);
    parentPanel.setEnabled(false);
    parentPanel.setDoubleBuffered(false);
    parentPanel.setDebugGraphicsOptions(DebugGraphics.NONE_OPTION);
    parentPanel.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    parentPanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    parentPanel.setBorder(null);
    parentPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 700));
    parentPanel.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);

    frame.getContentPane().add(parentPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

    /* BACKGAMMON BOARD LABEL-->PANEL */
    ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(
            new ImageIcon("images/bg.png").getImage()
                    .getScaledInstance(800, 551, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    parentPanel.setLayout(null);
    ImageIcon imageIcon1 = new ImageIcon(
            new ImageIcon("images/pl.png").getImage()
                    .getScaledInstance(50, 50, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

    image1 = new JLabel("");
    image1.setBounds(37, 36, 50, 50);
    parentPanel.add(image1);
    image1.setIcon(imageIcon1);



    JLabel bg = new JLabel("");
    bg.setBounds(10, 11, 800, 551);
    bg.setIcon(imageIcon);
    parentPanel.add(bg);
}

void movePiece(int pos, int dest) {
    //null exception happens here, ignore the arguments
    image1.setLocation(37 + 50,36);

}
```

Comment: Normally I'd be apposed to the suggestion, but you might want to have a look at [Doing Without a Layout Manager (Absolute Positioning)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).  You might also find [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) useful.

Comment: If time allowed I'd normally suggest doing this through the use of custom painting and taking complete control of the UI and it's layout. Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: What's calling `movePiece` in your code?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong here, but you don't actually call movePiece() at all, do you? The error still occurs with that in mind?

Comment: Excuse me for not including it, I'm gonna edit the startGame() method right now.

@MadProgrammer I read your first link before, I can't really make much of it. My problem seems weird in the sense that it should be working, but it isn't because of poorly generated code. I can't pinpoint the error because of my lack of experience in Java Graphics

Comment: I will be using this method to move every piece at the time that it is moved. Only way it works is if the     setLocation() method is called inside     initialize(), where the image is drawn.

Comment: You're having a "reference" issue.  Creating two distinct instances of the same object doesn't allow you to manipulate the properties of either from the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an instance of `Main` and make it visible...

```
Main window = new Main();
window.frame.setVisible(true);
```

You then create a new instance of `Main`, which, through it's constructor, calls your `moviePiece` method...

```
new Main(1);
```

But the new instance of `Main` has nothing to do with the previous instance or any of the components which they created.

Instead, trying doing...

```
window.movePiece(Move.getPos(), Move.getDest());
```

instead of `new Main(1);`

Comment: My god.. That was silly. But now another problem surfaces. When the initialize method is called, it returns and draws the Board. Then the game has to be started by calling the method startGame(), but I can't do it there because it is non-static and it has to remain that way. If i put startGame() after initialize() in the Main() constructor, it will never return because startGame() returns only when the game has ended. So, no board is drawn that way. The piece moved though, so thanks man.